# What is this thing under my window frame?

Tags: walls, condensation, window-frame

I've got 2 windows, one with a block of some sort under the frame, and one without. On the one without, in winter, condensation tends to form on the frame, and then the water trickles down the wall.

[image: with the block]

[image: without the block]

What is that block ? How can I make a similar one ?

Comment: Looks to me like a support for a badly fitted window.

Comment: The block looks like a 1/2 or 3/4 inch piece of wood/wood like material(plywood).  It also looks like a boo-boo hider.

Comment: Looks like something (a piece of wood?) used to be there.

Comment: The window with condensation probably has a cold air leak from not enough insulation or bad sealing(air/vapour).  It should fixed before adding anything else.

Comment: Wow, that's a bodge job if ever I saw one. Those decorative infill around the edges are meant to be just that - decorative. It looks like they used them to frame the existing window frame rather than remove it & mount the cassettes properly into the walls. They're just plonked on top, which makes the infills almost structural. They probably didn't bother to foam the gaps either. Can you feel the wind at the gaps?

Answer (score 1):

Like some of the comments have said, you are getting condensation there probably because of cold air leakage under the window frame.  That needs to be fixed first.  Also there should be insulation of some sort around the entire frame - between it and the wall framing.

Like this:
[image]

Note the low expansion foam along the side and under the frame of the window.